# Bash $_ in Python os.system

Tags: linux, bash, python

I just ran into the following

```
grep -h ^ID= /etc/*-release
python -c 'from os import system; system("echo hello; echo $_")'
```

for RHEL, this gives what i expect (`$_` expands to `hello`):

```
$ grep -h ^ID= /etc/*-release
ID="rhel"

$ python -c 'from os import system; system("echo hello; echo $_")'
hello
hello
```

but for Ubuntu (WSL) not:

```
$ grep -h ^ID= /etc/*-release
ID=ubuntu

$ python -c 'from os import system; system("echo hello; echo $_")'
hello
/usr/bin/python
```

why is that?

Comment: You should probably avoid `os.system` anyway. `os.environ["SHELL"]` contains the value of the variable, and `subprocess.run(["echo", "hello"])` runs an external command. [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) explains why you might want to avoid `os.system` and/or `shell=True` with `subprocess`.

Comment: Tangentially, probably avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat); `grep` knows how to process multiple input files just fine (use `grep -H` to avoid having the file names printed).

Comment: @tripleee the `$SHELL` was just for demonstration, I am considering to remove it from the question. :)

Comment: @tripleee I am an the iterative process of converting shell to python and some steps are simply easier to keep for as `os.system` in the first iteration. The steps are properly replaced with python now. But I was curious as to *why* this is/was happening. :)

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` delegates to the C `system()` function:

> `os.system(command)`
>
> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This is implemented by calling the Standard C function `system()`
>
> -- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system

which on Linux is defined as:

> ```
> int system(const char *command);
> ```
>
> The `system()` library function uses `fork(2)` to create a child
> process that executes the shell command specified in `command`
> using `execl(3)` as follows:
>
> ```
> execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) NULL);
> ```
>
> -- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html

On RHEL `sh` is `bash`, but on Ubuntu it's `dash`.

`$_` is undefined in `dash`, it is a bash functionality, thus the discrepancy.

On Ubuntu/Debian You can set bash-as-sh using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash` and selecting "No" in the dialog.